# error while setting authorities with Spring security

Tags: java, spring-security

I use spring security and have some problems when starting the authentication process

Here is my class USER

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="MEMBRE")
public class Membre  implements UserDetails, Serializable {

    ...................
    private ArrayList<Role> authorities;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="MEMBRE_ROLE",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_membre", referencedColumnName="id_membre")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_role", referencedColumnName="id_role")})
    public Collection<Role> getAuthorities() {
        return this.authorities;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(ArrayList<Role> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }
    ................
    }
```

Here is my class Role (GrantedAuthority)

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="ROLE")
public class Role  implements GrantedAuthority, Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4160725609927520747L;

    private Integer id;

    private String role;

    @Transient
    public String getAuthority() {
        return this.role;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id_role", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 9, scale = 0)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

Here is my table MEMBRE_ROLE

```
    CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MEMBRE_ROLE` (
  `id_role` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `id_membre` INT NOT NULL),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_role`, `id_membre`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_membre_role_membre`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_membre` )
    REFERENCES `membre` (`id_membre` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_membre_role_role`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_role` )
    REFERENCES `role` (`id_role` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

And when I try to authenticate, I get the following error

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property [domain.Membre.authorities (expected type = java.util.ArrayList)]; target = [domain.Membre@1807f3f2], property value = [[domain.Role@16cc0706, domain.Role@88b48]] setter of domain.Membre.authorities; nested exception is IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property [domain.Membre.authorities (expected type = java.util.ArrayList)]; target = [domain.Membre@1807f3f2], property value = [[domain.Role@16cc0706, domain.Role@88b48]]

I understand that the setter isn't properly defined, but I can' see how to manage it and if the mapping of authorities is properly defined considering spring security

Answer (score 1):

To not confuse JPA, use the same type for field, getter and setter:

```java
private Collection<Role> authorities;

public Collection<Role> getAuthorities() {
    return this.authorities;
}

public void setAuthorities(Collection<Role> authorities) {
    this.authorities = authorities;
}
```

(JPA annotations omitted for brevity.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to debug repacing my setter method by

```
    public void setAuthorities(Object authorities) {
    this.authorities = (ArrayList<Role>)authorities;
}
```

And I get a PersistentBag as argument for authorities
Here is the inspection of authorities expression

- Authorities
- bag  --> ArrayList

  - elementData --> Object[10]

    - [0] -->  Role
    - [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmqsb.png) -->  Role

How to get an ArrayList as argument ? I suppose there is an issue with the mapping.

I found this post on internet, but it didn't give me a solution that works

http://www.coderanch.com/t/431759/ORM/databases/JPA-returning-collection-type-PersistentBag

Answer (score 0):

finally I found a temporary solution, not very elegant, but it works. If you have a better solution ..........

```
public void setAuthorities(PersistentBag authorities) {
final List<Object> listObject = Arrays.asList(authorities.toArray());
final ArrayList<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
for (final Object object : listObject) {
    if (object instanceof Role) {
        roles.add((Role)object);
    }
}
this.authorities = roles;
```

}